# XBMC won't live boot

Tags: linux, boot, livecd, kodi

I'm trying to run XBMC on a Dell Dimension 4300S (stock parts).  I cannot get it to finish a live boot.  It gets stuck on "restarting openbsd secure shell server sshd" [see picture].

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one wanted to help me, I figured it out myself. I just installed it as software on the machine.  Setup the third-party software key and updates and I was good to go.  Just installed through the terminal and it runs like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [XBMC Live](http://xbmc.org/wiki/?title=XBMC_Live) is based on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) ([mobile](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/mobile)),
it might help to try a Ubuntu Live CD boot on your hardware.
It would give you a better debug environment to check what is blocking it.

<sup>The [XBMC Hardware Discussion](http://xbmc.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?s=087626a1346ac1d79d0e1eac9983578b&f=112) forum may also have useful notes -- but, I have not checked that.</sup>

---

Update: Can you confirm that a regular Ubuntu LiveCD works fine?

---

Update2: Hardware limitations (and driver support) is what I suspect.
Maybe you should install XBMC on a regular Ubuntu and check out the dependencies required for it to work on your hardware. You could do this with a USB Installed Ubuntu with XBMC added in (and other required updates). This would work fine off a 8 GB USB (maybe even 4GB).

Comment: The computer is running Ubuntu.  That what I was using prior to XBMC to stream media from my home server.

Comment: I can confirm that it does work fine.  That is obviously what I used to install it initially.  I tested the XBMU livecd on another machine to see if it was a bad iso, and there's nothing wrong with the cd.  It booted fine into my lenovo notebook.  ------  Think maybe the specs are too low?  Because when I ran it in safe mode to boot with an "ATI/AMD GPU" I think I remember it dictating something about not recognizing ATI/AMD hardware, when in fact it does contain an ATI GPU.